# Prism mvvm - TabControl does not display data

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, prism, tabcontrol

I'm using Prism. I have a ContextControl region, and a view associated with that region. Within the view is a TabControl. The controls are displaying data with no problem, but the controls within the TabControl are not displaying any data. I have tried setting the DataContext and ItemsSource(for the TabControl) , without success. The data to be displayed is from the SelectedSession class.

xaml

```
 <!--session data grid-->
        <Grid x:Name="SessionDataGrid"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentControl
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="0 0 0 0"
                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="DataRegion"/>
        </Grid>
```

View

```
<!--row 0-->
<Label x:Name="labelSessionData" 
            Content="Session Data" 
            Style="{DynamicResource LabelGeneric}" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="1,2,0,0"/>

    <!--row 1-->
    <Label x:Name="labelSessionDataIdentifier" 
            Content="Identifier: " 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
            Style="{DynamicResource LabelGeneric}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxSessionDataIdentifier" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.Row="1"         
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Style="{DynamicResource textBoxDataN}" 
            Text="{Binding SelectedSession.Identifier, Mode=OneWay}" 
            Width="230"
             Margin="0 4 0 3"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelSessionDataCamera" 
            Content="Camera: " 
            Grid.Column="2" 
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
            Style="{DynamicResource LabelGeneric}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboboxSessionDataCamera" 
            Grid.Column="3" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            IsEditable="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Cameras}"
            DisplayMemberPath="CameraName" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSession.CameraId, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedValuePath="CameraId"
            Style="{DynamicResource ComboboxData}"                 
            Width="230"
            Margin="0 0 0 0"/>
    
            <!--row 3-->            
    
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControlSessionData" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
            Grid.Row="3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
           
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="0,0,10,0"
            Visibility="Hidden">
        <TabItem Header="Analog">
            <Grid Background="{StaticResource MainBackgroundColor}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="83"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
                <!--row 0-->
                <Label x:Name="labelSessionAnalogFilm" 
                       Content="Film: " 
                       Grid.Column="0" 
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Grid.Row="0" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource LabelGeneric}" 
                       Margin="1,1,0,0"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="comboboxSessionAnalogFilm" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Films}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="FilmName"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSession.FilmId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedValuePath="FilmID"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ComboboxData}" 
                        Margin="0 0 0 0"/>
                <Label x:Name="labelSessionAnalogISO" 
                        Content="ISO: " 
                        Grid.Column="4" 
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                        Style="{DynamicResource LabelGeneric}" 
                        Margin="2,1,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBoxSessionAnalogFilmISO" 
                        Grid.Column="5" 
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Style="{DynamicResource textBoxDataN}" 
                        Text="{Binding FilmISO, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        Width="50" 
                        Margin="0,4"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the data from a DataGrid. Once I defined the columns for the data it started working.